# Put outcome from from nslookup into columns

Tags: linux, nslookup

I have a list of hosts in a testfile. I am trying to organize the output into 3 columns.
I want to do nslookup on hostname and ilo-hostname and put the result into columns as below.

```
Hostname    IP-hostname ilo-hosntame
Host-1           FQN        FQN 
Host-2           FQN           ** server can't find Host-2: SERVFAIL
```

Edit:
I now have a file that looks like this

Hostname 
IloHostname
Hotname
IloHostname
Hostname** server can't find IloHostname: SERVFAIL //when Ilohostname is not found or does not exist

Script used to create this file

```
egrep 'Name:|SERVFAIL' list3 | awk '{sub(/Name:/,"")}; 1' | awk '{$1=$1}1' | awk -F. '{print $1}'
```

list3 is output from nslookup

Answer (score 0):

You might use `host` instead of `nslookup`. It's output format is a little more amenable to post-processing to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 This perl code maybe could be useful with some modifications:

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while(<DATA>){
    my %table;
    print;
    my @res = qx/nslookup $_/;
    my @eres = grep {/(\w+)\:\s+(\S+)\s*/g} @res;
    #now you got it
    foreach my $r (@eres){
        if ($r =~ /Name:(.*)/) {print "$1\t"}
        if ($r =~ /Address:(.*)\n/ and not $r =~ /\#/) {print "$1\n"}
    }
}

__DATA__
www.cisco.com
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
```